# How to prevent rendered image from being cropped?

Tags: rendering

My scene is set to 1920 x 1080 px.

[image]

The image is cropped to a square of about 600 x 600 px when rendered.

[image]

It doesn't matter where I place the camera; the render is always the same.

The rendered image matches the bounds of the dotted orange box in the left window of  Animation.

[image: blender make dotted orange box in the Blender animation window larger]

How do I increase this? It might increase the bounds of the final image.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to turn off *Render Region*.

Turn off *Render Region* to prevent Blender image render being cropped.
[image: turn off Render Region to prevent Blender image render being cropped]

Comment: And if you are wondering why it was turned on: you probably have accidentally used Ctrl+B in camera view to define a render region, this enables the _Render Region_ option (if you didn't just click the checkbox). To get rid of it you don't have to go to the _Output Properties_ panel, you can simply hit Ctrl+Alt+B in the camera view. Or simply define a region with Ctrl+B larger than the camera view, this will let you render the whole image but renders the viewport only within the camera view, which can help with performance in rendered mode.

Comment: By the way, you can also define a render region in the _3D Viewport_ when you are not in camera view. This way you can limit the rendered mode in the viewport to a certain area. If you do it outside of camera view, it will not affect rendering the image (option _Render Region_ is not enabled by this). Switching the render border off with the Ctrl+Alt+B shortcut is dependent on the view it was enabled in - if it was in camera view, you need to switch it off in camera view. If it was outside of camera view, you need to do it there. You can define different areas at the same time for each view.